# How to send *shell* stdout directly to kill-ring?

Tags: shell, shell-mode, kill-ring, clipboard

Suppose that I have a `*shell*` buffer (i.e. a subordinate shell, started with `M-x shell`).  Suppose also that at this shell's prompt, I can execute some command `foo` that sends some output to `stdout`.

I know that, in general, I can always select the region in the `*shell*` buffer corresponding to `foo`'s output and add it to the kill-ring with `C-w`.

I'd like, however, to pipe `foo`'s output *directly* to the kill-ring, so that it never appears in the `*shell*` buffer (and thus obviating the need to select the appropriate region and run `C-w`).

Is there a way to do this?

For example, is there some Unix command `bar` such that running

```
% foo | bar
```

...in the `*shell*` buffer will cause the output of `foo` to be added to Emacs's kill-ring?

---

In case there's a difference between them, I'd like to know the answer to this question for 3 different cases (in order of importance):

1. Emacs is running as an X11 application (Debian Linux + Xfce4 + Xfwm4);
2. Emacs is running in "text-only mode" (e.g. started with `emacs -nw`);
3. Emacs is running as a Cocoa application in OS X (i.e. it is `/Applications/Emacs.app`, installed from [here](https://emacsformacosx.com/));

---

<sup>PS: I just learned that `eshell` (not to be confused with `M-x shell`/`comint`) implements the `/dev/kill` pseudo-file, which solve's this post's problem (i.e. `foo > /dev/kill` adds `foo`'s output to the kill-ring).  Unfortunately, IME, using `eshell` has always been an *absolute nightmare*, since so little of what I know from `bash` works with `eshell`; I don't want to learn a whole new---and totally weird--shell from the bottom up just to solve this post's problem.  Therefore, at the moment at least, `eshell`-based solutions are out of the question.  This may change, however, depending on the answers I get to [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/30463/882) I just posted.</sup>

Comment: I came here looking for the `/dev/kill` eshell thing. Thanks for your edit at the bottom!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Emacs Command

Instead of select-and-copy manually, you can also write a command and
let it do the work for you:

```el
;; Adapted from `comint-delete-output'
(defun comint-copy-output ()
  "Copy all output from interpreter since last input."
  (interactive)
  (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (save-excursion
      (let ((pmark (progn (goto-char (process-mark proc))
              (forward-line 0)
              (point-marker))))
    (kill-new (buffer-substring comint-last-input-end pmark))))))
```

### foo | bar

Your idea can also be achieved by a simple shell script. It assumes
Emacs server is running, if it is not, you can start it via the
command `server-start` or run Emacs as a daemon.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat /dev/stdin > /tmp/clip

emacsclient --eval '(kill-new (my-file-contents "/tmp/clip"))'
```

Becuase it's not easy to embedding Lisp code in shell,
`my-file-contents` is defined in Emacs.

```el
(defun my-file-contents (file)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (buffer-string)))
```

Now in shell, `% foo | bar` should do what you want (assuming `bar`
is the shell script and it is in your PATH).

### foo > /tmp/kill

In Eshell, you can save output to the kill ring by redirecting output
to `/dev/kill`. You can do the similar in any shell:

1. redirect output to `/tmp/kill`
2. when the contents of `/tmp/kill` changes, make Emacs copies the new
   contents to the kill ring

(notes that your Emacs should be compiled with support of watching
filesystem, I guess it means `(require 'filenotify)` should return
non-nil)

```el
(defun save-to-kill-ring-if-changes (event)
  ;; (message "Event %S" event)
  (when (eq (cadr event) 'changed)
    (kill-new (my-file-contents "/tmp/kill"))))

;; Create /tmp/kill firstly
(write-region "" nil "/tmp/kill")
(file-notify-add-watch "/tmp/kill" '(change) 'save-to-kill-ring-if-changes)
```

then in any shell, `% foo > /tmp/kill` should copy the output of `foo`
to the kill ring.